# Writing data to disk in parallel?

Tags: multithreading, image-processing, c++-cli

So I am working on a C++/cli image processing library and am trying to optimize my code. Basically, I am passed a System::Drawing::Bitmap of the image, which I then need to write to disk, perform complex analysis on, and return the results of the analysis. I thought that I could write the image to disk in parallel to speed up things (my algorithm does not modify the image). However, I have not worked with threads much, so I wanted to get your input on what the best way to do this would be.

```
string ProcessImage(System::Drawing::Bitmap ^bmp, System::String^ targetFile)
{
    bmp->Save(targetFile);
    System::Drawing::Bitmap^ bmp8 = BitmapConvertPixelFormat(bmp, 8); //<-- a function I wrote which converts the 32bpp I am passed into an 8bpp one
    string results = Analyze(bmp8); //<--- takes a good bit of time
    return results;
}
```

Please let me know your thoughts.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: need more specification. do you want to (1) write data that's available before analysis starts, (2) write data that's generated by analysis, while analysis is ongoing, or (3) write data that's only available once analysis is complete? Or something else entirely?

Comment: @JustJeff: from the sample code he's giving, I believe it's the (1) case. Which is trivially a case where threading will help without too much work.

Comment: @LieRyan - agreed. still would like OP to confirm

Comment: This is pointless.  You may have multiple cores but you still have only one disk.  It is a memory-to-memory copy anyway when the image isn't larger than a gigabyte or so, depending on the size of the file system cache.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Writing/reading in parallel to/from a single mechanical disk is not a good idea because the mechanical head needs to spin every time to service an I/O request, so using multiple threads will just bounce it around needlessly and create overhead.

You can try to benchmark a bit, but I'm afraid you'll just have to resort to using a single thread and writing sequentially.

Comment: not true. In practically any non-trivial OS, your disk reads/writes are buffered by the OS.

Comment: @Lie Ryan: Even if the I/O requests get buffered and issued later, and even if they would somehow be reordered in an optimal pattern (which is wishful thinking), it would still be at most as efficient as a single writer thread.

Comment: I thought OP meant "perform complex analysis" in parallel with disk writing, as opposed to writing one part of the output in parallel with writing another part.

Comment: @JustJeff: Good point. Now that I read again it's not clear whether he means to "write the image in parallel" or "write the image in parallel with the analysis".

Comment: I know from practice that this answer is correct. At least Windows does not optimize writing from multiple threads. Try to copy two files at the same time to see what I mean. Throughput gets *destroyed*.

Comment: Huh? I am not reading from disk at all. I am only analyzing the image and writing the original input data to disk. Do you mean to say that I can't optimize this code at all?

Comment: @Amil: Do you intend to write the image itself in parallel (i.e. multiple threads each writing a piece of the image in parallel) or do you want to write the image with one thread and do the rest of the stuff with another one?

Comment: @Tudor I didn't think about writing pieces of the image in parallel! Whatever is faster.

Answer (score 3):

Queueing off the disk writes to another thread seems like a qood idea, but only to one writer thread per disk so that the complex analysis can run on without the slow disk-writes holding it up.

Comment: Nothing much to synchronize because the analysis code does not modify the data.  It's the analysis input data that is written to disk, not output, so they can proceed in parallel.  Regarding lifetime management of the data, the OP does not provide any constraints, so I didn't bother mentioning it.  If the data has to be delete()ed, after these operations, then I would probably use an atomic refCount so that the last of analysis/writer to finish deletes the data object.

Answer (score 1):

If it's worth it you can invest some time into understanding how to use [Parallel HDF5](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/Tutor/pprog.html). It can write to a file in parallel.