# Execution time of thread changes

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm using this method: [Measure execution time in C (on Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15720542/measure-execution-time-in-c-on-windows) to measure the execution time of all threads. I'm on Windows and I'm using VC++.

Something like this:

```
//initialize start, end, frequency
std::thread thread1(...); 
// and so on I initialise all the threads

thread1.join();
//join all threads

//time = (start-end)/frequency
printf(time);
```

I run it multiple times and I often get different execution time. I have like 30% variation.(which means I get values between 100s and 70s). I don't understand why ? 30% is not I small variation.

Thanks

Comment: How do you measure time? Consider measuring processor time if you're measuring astronomical since the latter depends on the system load

Comment: Time measurement resolution is limited by scheduling and other factors.  The shorter the thread run time, the more inaccurate your timing will be.  I would take an average of many runs.

Comment: @alexeykuzmin0  same as in the answer of the question I linked I copy paste. Using QueryPerformanceCounter.

Comment: You're measuring "wall-clock" time, not the time spent in your own process.

Comment: @molbdnilo How should I measure the time spent in my own process ?

Comment: 30% variation is not a lot, but a variation from 70 seconds to 100 seconds is gigantic. It means there is room from improvement in whatever thread1 is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Many things can affect an execution time, from system load to memory usage to the stars aligning. You don't specify the order of your execution time, but for lower values a 30% deviation is certainly not unheard of. The main take away is that an execution time on its own basically tells us nothing about the system.

Comment: so what your saying is the there is no way I could no exactly how much time it takes to execute my program ? Because in my case it's really important to know the exact execution time. Thanks

Comment: There's no such thing as an "exact execution time" in the general case. You can do multiple runs and take an average, or you can take the time of a single run, but there's no way to say "This program will take exactly n seconds to run" in the general case.

Comment: @userDS *exact execution time* is the property of what you call real time operating systems. Windows is not one of them. That said a 30s variation is questionable, except if you access slow resources like disk or network. So investigate. there is something fishy.

Comment: @UmNyobe I write to the disk every time.

Comment: @userDS there you have it. you need all the thread to send data to a single thread which is charge of writing (multiple producer, single consumer). see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10254147/writing-data-to-disk-in-parallel

Comment: @UmNyobe you are right thanks. Is there anything that I can do to improve my performance. For ex have one more disk, or write to an external disk, anything ?

Comment: @userDS multiple thread compute, only one thread write to ***one*** faster disk.

Answer (score 0):

`QueryPerformanceCounter` is a system-wide counter, so your result depends on system load and the particulars of the process scheduling.

You could use [`QueryProcessCycleTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684929(v=vs.85).aspx), which returns

> The number of CPU clock cycles used by the threads of the process. This value includes cycles spent in both user mode and kernel mode.

You can get a handle to the current process using [`GetCurrentProcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683179(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: What should I pass as HANDLE   ProcessHandle ? How can I create this handle object ? Thanks